# Rspec test failed in GitLab CI with Headless Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, gitlab-ci, google-chrome-headless

I have below spec code for testing user login feature.

```
feature "User login" do
    context "using browser", :js => true do
        before(:each) do
            visit "/"
            first(:link, "Login", visible: :any).click
        end
        scenario "with valid details" do
          ...
          # rest of code.
        end
    end
end
```

It is working fine in my local machine with headless chrome. Here is my `Capybara javascript_driver` config in *spec_helper.rb*.

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox]
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

But not working with **gitlab-ci**, below is error i am getting.

> **Failure/Error: first(:link, "Login", visible: :any).click**
>
> **NoMethodError: undefined method 'click' for nil:NilClass**
>   ./spec/features/user_login_spec.rb:6:in 'block (3 levels) in '
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.6/lib/rspec/retry.rb:115:in
>   'block in run'
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.6/lib/rspec/retry.rb:104:in
>   'loop'
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.6/lib/rspec/retry.rb:104:in
>   'run'
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-retry-0.5.6/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in
>   'run_with_retry'

I found [this blog](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/12/19/moving-to-headless-chrome/) to use headless chrome but nothing helped.

Here are the versions of dependencies i am using.

```
google-chrome-stable (63.0.3239.108-1)
chromedriver (2.34)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `first` doesn't have waiting/retrying behavior, which means if a matching link doesn't exist when it runs it won't wait for one to appear.  Additionally passing `visible: :any` to find an element that you're then going to call `click` on doesn't make any sense since you can't click on non-visible elements so that would cause an error too.  If you do actually need/want to use `first` (multiple matching links that you can't scope down to one) then you should be using

```
before(:each) do
  visit "/"
  first(:link, "Login", minimum: 1).click
end
```

The `minimum: 1` option will trigger first to wait/retry up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for a matching link to appear on the page.  This is one of the reasons using `first` and `all` are generally 
 bad choices when looking for elements to actually interact with (unless you've done a previous find for something that guarantees the page is in a stable state, or use any of the count options to trigger waiting/retrying behavior). If there aren't actually more than one matching link on the page then you should just be using

```
before(:each) do
  visit "/"
  click_link('Login') # same as find(:link, 'Login').click
end
```

Comment: This make sense, I will try and get back to you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: now i am getting this error `Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
     #   expected to find visible link "Login" at least 1 time but there were no matches
     #   /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.16.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:268:in 'block in all'`

Comment: @Satendra Then the link isn’t on the page - check what `page.html` is after the visit

Comment: But it is working on my local machine, and not running on gitlab-ci runner. How can i debug there?

Comment: I checked my log and found `2017-12-29 07:54:06 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>`, it is something related to connection issue with chrome engine